# Gutenberg extend core blocks

Tags: block-editor, customization

How do I modify a core block, in my case gallery block to add extra markup to can fire some lightbox on created gallery. Is there a way to hook in on render of gallery on frontpage to adjust markup?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use [Block Filters](https://wordpress.org/gutenberg/handbook/designers-developers/developers/filters/block-filters/) to modify existing blocks. There are couple of handy hooks you need to use in place of **edit** and **save** function to wrap around core blocks into your desirable block structure.

For your purpose I guess, you need to use - blocks.getSaveElement and editor.BlockEdit